# How to autoupadate a shiny app with new data?

Tags: r, shiny, auto-update

I want to force a highcharter chart, inside shiny app to plot new data from Mysql database. I've tried different approaches but none seems to work.
At first my connection to sql through library(RMySQL) & library(pool) in globalR

```
#--------Connect to SQL----------#

pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "xxx",
  host = "x.x.x.x",
  username = 'xxxx',
  password = 'xxxx'
)

sql1 <- 'SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `datetime` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY'

query1 <- sqlInterpolate(pool, sql1)

notifier1 <- dbGetQuery(pool, sqlInterpolate(pool,'SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `datetime` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY' ))

lapply(dbListConnections( dbDriver( drv = "MySQL")), dbDisconnect)
```

then I create 2 dataframes

```
all1 <- as.data.frame(notifier1%>% group_by(datetime, customer) %>% count(ping) %>% filter(datetime > Sys.time()-14400) %>%
             mutate(percent = (round(100 * n/sum(n), 1))) %>% filter(ping=='1') %>% arrange(desc(datetime)))


 all1_new <- transform(all1,datetime=as.numeric(as.POSIXct(datetime))*1000)
```

In server I've tried:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {  

     observeEvent(invalidateLater(60000, session),{
             notifier1 <- dbGetQuery(pool, sqlInterpolate(pool,'SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `datetime` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY' ))

             all1 <- as.data.frame(notifier1%>% group_by(datetime, customer) %>% count(ping) %>% filter(datetime > Sys.time()-14400) %>% 
                                        mutate(percent = (round(100 * n/sum(n), 1))) %>% filter(ping=='1') %>% arrange(desc(datetime)))


             all1_new <- transform(all1,datetime= as.numeric(as.POSIXct(datetime))*1000)
     })
```

and the highchart code that I need to display new data every e.g 1 min:

```
output$Plot1 <- renderHighchart ({

        # invalidateLater(60000,session)



    highchart() %>%
         hc_chart(type = "container",
                  zoomType= "x"
         ) %>%
         #axis
         hc_xAxis(type='datetime',
                  # categories=c(min2$datetime),
                  labels = list(rotation = 90,
                                format = '{value:%e-%b %H:%M}'),
                  showLastLabel = TRUE
         ) %>% 
         hc_yAxis(opposite = FALSE, 
                  title = list(text = "Call Success"),
                  labels = list(format = "{value}%", style=list(fontSize='13px')), max = 100) %>% 
         hc_add_series(all1_new, "spline", hcaes(x=datetime, y=percent, group=customer)
         )%>%
      })
```

Comment: Maybe have a look at `?shiny::reactivePoll`

Comment: I've tried reactivePoll with no success either. Seems more complicated & I don't hane that experience yet..

Comment: It would be easier to help with a fully reproducible example (e.g. using a dummy SQLite db, and a separate R process that fills it periodically)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could look like:

```
check_db_update <- function() {
  dbGetQuery(pool, sqlInterpolate(pool, 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `results`' 
  ))
}

get_data_from_db <- function() {
  dbGetQuery(pool, sqlInterpolate(pool,
    'SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `datetime` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY' 
  ))
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data_rx <- 
    reactivePoll(intervalMillis = 6e4, session = session,
                 checkFunc = check_db_update, valueFunc = get_data_from_db)

  data_wrangled_rx <- reactive({
    data_rx() %>% 
      group_by(datetime, customer) %>% 
      count(ping)
    # ...
  })

  output$Plot1 <- renderHighchart ({
    highchart() %>% 
      hc_add_series(data = data_wrangled_rx())
    # ...
  })

  # ...
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error: {Error in .local(dbObj, ...) : 
  internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle}

Comment: This is pseudo-code, so it's practically impossible to debug the error message without more context and a fully reproducible example. How did you adapt suggested code?

Comment: 'pool <- dbPool(
  drv = RMySQL::MySQL(),
  dbname = "",
  host = "",
  username = '',
  password = ''
)

check_db_update <- function() {
   dbGetQuery(pool, sqlInterpolate(pool, 
    'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `results`' ))
}

get_data_from_db <- function() {
     dbGetQuery(pool, sqlInterpolate(pool,
    'SELECT * FROM `results` WHERE `datetime` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY' ))
  }'

Comment: Ok, and what appears to be the problem? Running this code just creates the pool and defines functions. Does the error stem from `pool <- dbPool(....)`? If yes, it has little to do with the Shiny logic

Comment: Thanks Aurele, it works fine now.  I only get a warning : 'Warning in (function (e)  : You have a leaked pooled object.
Warning in value[[3L]](cond) :
  Object of class MySQLConnection could not be destroyed properly, but was successfully removed from pool. Error message: internal error in RS_DBI_getConnection: corrupt connection handle'   Any clues about it?